# Why is string.Join(string, object[]) special?

Tags: .net, string

I was looking at the following expressions:

```
string.Join(",", new object[] { null, "StackOverflow" })
string.Join(",", new string[] { null, "StackOverflow" })
string.Join(",", new object[] { string.Empty, "StackOverflow" })
string.Join(",", new string[] { string.Empty, "StackOverflow" })
```

I would have thought they would return the same value:

```
,StackOverflow
```

However, the first expression actually returns `string.Empty`. This [is actually defined behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the first element of values is null, the Join(String, Object[]) method does not concatenate the elements in values but instead returns String.Empty. A number of workarounds for this issue are available. The easiest is to assign a value of String.Empty to the first element of the array, as the following example shows.

Does anyone know the reason behind this inconsistency?

Comment: With that sort of phrasing ("workaround", "issue"), I would assume that it's a bug and not an intended behavior...

Comment: @Vache No, That is coded intentionally. open it in reflector to see..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yeah I can see that, but a few lines below there is some code that seems contradictory with this behavior. There is an `if` handling a null value for the first element's string representation.

Comment: @Vache Yes I can see that. Also note this stupid restriction is only for this overload of `Join` method. other implementation looks fine

Answer (score 3):

In your favorite decompiler you can see that the code for the method is

```
public static string Join(string separator, params object[] values)
{
  if (values == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
  if (values.Length == 0 || values[0] == null)
    return string.Empty;
  if (separator == null)
    separator = string.Empty;
  StringBuilder sb = StringBuilderCache.Acquire(16);
  string str1 = values[0].ToString();
  if (str1 != null)
    sb.Append(str1);
  for (int index = 1; index < values.Length; ++index)
  {
    sb.Append(separator);
    if (values[index] != null)
    {
      string str2 = values[index].ToString();
      if (str2 != null)
        sb.Append(str2);
    }
  }
  return StringBuilderCache.GetStringAndRelease(sb);
}
```

The part responsible for the special behavior is

```
  if (values.Length == 0 || values[0] == null)
    return string.Empty;
```

but we can see a few lines below

```
  string str1 = values[0].ToString();
  if (str1 != null)
    sb.Append(str1);
```

It seems quite strange to me to return on `values[0] == null` but to handle `values[0].ToString() == null`. Combined with the wording on MSDN ("issue", "workaround"), the fact that this overload is relatively new (.NET 4.0) and the fact the the other `Join`s have a different implementation that accept `null` as the first element, it looks like a bug to me and not really an intended exception.

Of course, this is only my interpretation and not a definitive answer...

Comment: Not sure `values[0].ToString() == null` indicates anything. It would throw a `NullReferenceException` if `values[0]` was `null`. It is checking to ensure someone isn't returning `null` from `ToString`.

Comment: For me it matters checking `values[0].ToString() == null` because `values[0]` may not be null but it can return null by overriding `ToString()`

Comment: @Anthony That's my point. We handle objects that have a `null` string representation, so why not handle `null` ? That looks inconsistent to me.