# String Join not working fine

Tags: c#, .net, string

Following code returns true, why?

```
var inputs = new object[]{null, 1};
var output = string.Join(",", inputs);
Console.WriteLine(output == "");//Prints True
```

### > `Output = ""`

But the following code is working fine

```
var inputs = new object[]{"", null, 1};
var output = string.Join(",", inputs);
Console.WriteLine(output == "");//Prints False
```

### > `Output = ",,1"`

Is something wrong in native implementation?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Both versions would not compile as `var output = string.Join(",", inputs) == "");` is missing a bracket.

Comment: Already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228075/why-is-string-joinstring-object-special

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the first element of values is `null`, the `Join(String, Object[])` method does not concatenate the elements in values but instead returns `String.Empty`.

Which is a special case for the overload using `object[]`. Note that this isn't true for the other overloads, like the `string[]` one.

Comment: ...which, however, is a bit surprising.